# In VISIO 2010, can UML Model Diagrams be combined with Database Model Diagram?

Tags: uml, visio

I'm new to using UML, but it seems to me UML models for software should be able to share information with database models.  I have a UML Model Diagram file and a Database Diagram file and I seem to be retyping a lot of strings in the two models.  I'm afraid this will be a mess when the names change.  Is there any way to link these up?  When I a copy parts of one into the other I get this:

[image]

Is the answer to not use Visio 2010?

Comment: Generally I'd not use a drawing tool but rather a UML modeling tool. Have a look at Enterprise Architect which has the best price/performance ratio. But there are also quite some free ones (like Visual Paradigm Community and others).

Comment: uml in visio is pretty terrible.... I usually draw my own class diagrams in visio, or stick to a UML product like asta